# growth curve modeling for nominal and ordinal dependent variables

Tags: categorical-data, growth-model, dependent-variable

Is it possible to conduct growth curve modeling for nominal and ordinal dependent variables instead of a continuous variable? The aim is to investigate the nature of the growth trajectories and to estimate mixed(fixed and random)effects with the help of the SPSS software program.
Note: The volume changes of a subcutaneous lesion (level one) with or without therapeutic intervention in different age/gender/racial groups of individuals (level two) have been measured during three time occasions. According to the researcher, reduction of dimensions and consequently volume to zero is a desirable response, but accidental rupture is risky and therefore an undesirable response. We want to define different types of response to treatment as an outcome variable with three categories in the model: more than x% volume reduction / less than x% volume reduction and rupture.
Ho: Mt1=Mt2=Mt3

Comment: Can you provide more information on what you are modelling and what your hypothesis is?

Comment: How exactly would any nominal variable "grow"??

Comment: Nb, some people seem to use the term 'growth curve model' to mean a LMM.  That may be the case here.

Comment: individual growth curve (IGC) analysis is known by many names; some of the more common ones are latent growth curve analysis, hierarchical linear modeling, mixed-effect modeling, random-effects modeling, and multilevel modeling. These labels mean essentially the same thing.